# Changing height of buttons in jQuery with .css not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have div and buttons. `.buttons` size is not changing.

(script.js is in the same directory as HTML index file.)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#next').click(function(){
        $('.button').css('height','1200');
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" ></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="slide_container">
        <div id="slide">

        </div>
        <a id='next' href="#">Next One</a>
        <input type="button" id="btnPrev" value="Prevous" class="button"/>
        <input type="button" id="btnNext" value="Next" class="button"/>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors do you have in the JavaScript console?

Comment: What you have will work, assuming you've included jQuery on the page... what does `script.js` contain? Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/hQNWy/7/

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Rq7xa/

Comment: Works for me, see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzuhf/). What browser are you using that it's not working in?

Comment: Are there any rules in your `style.css` which will be applied to the `button`s? Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ur6T/1/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think You have not included jQuery Library.

Try including this and post errors from error console

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: might be worth adding that you can use the Google CDN to source the jQuery library `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Good Morning,

It looks as if your next id is not named correctly (unless I'm missing something).

In your example you have the following line:

```
<input type="button" id="btnNext" value="Next" class="button"/>
```

Based on that, your jQuery needs to be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnNext').click(function(){
        $('.button').css('height','1200');
    });
});
```

Let me know if that doesn't work!

JMax

Comment: `next` is the id of the anchor next to the 2 buttons!

Comment: Duh. Thanks. Can't believe I missed that ;).

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to have included a reference to the jQuery library.

Add this to the head section (assuming jquery is in the same folder):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without further information, I can only assume that the link is being followed before the effect takes place, to avoid that (and to prevent the link from being followed (and a new page opened)):

```
$('#next').click(function(){
    $('.button').css('height','1200');
    return false;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MDmwa/).

Return false both prevents the default behaviour of the element (a new page being loaded) *and* stops propagation of the click event, if you only want to prevent the navigation aspect/default behaviour, you can instead use:

```
$('#next').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.button').css('height','1200');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MDmwa/1/).

Comment: The worst that will happen for this particular anchor is the user will be taken back to the top of the page, since the `href` is just `#`. Still a good idea to call `preventDefault()` so they don't get annoyed, though.